# Signed multiplier Verilog

Tags: verilog, hardware

I am designing a processor in Verilog. I'm working on the ALU, specifically the multiplier for the ALU. I can get the correct results when performing multiplication with small, positive numbers, but if I try to multiply signed numbers I get issues. When a positive number multiplies a negative the result will not sign extend all the way to 64 bits, and if two negative numbers are multiplied the number is incorrect altogether (sign and value). Can anyone see where the issue lies? I assumed I was not performing an arithmetic shift but I adjusted that and am still getting the wrong results.

```
module multiplier(
        input[31:0] operand1,
        input[31:0] operand2,
        output reg [63:0] product
    );

reg [64:0] prod;
reg [31:0] mcand;
reg [31:0] sum;
integer i = 0;


always @* begin


   prod = {32'b0,operand1}; 
   mcand = operand2;

    for(i=0;i<32;i=i+1) begin

        //test 0 bit of product
        case(prod[0])
            1'b0:begin        //if prod[0] == 0, arithmetic shift right
                    prod = prod>>>1;
            end

            1'b1:begin    //if prod[0] == 1, add multiplicand to upper 32
                             //bits and arithmetic shift right
                    prod = {(prod[63:32]+mcand[31:0]),prod[31:0]};
                    prod = prod>>>1;
                end
        endcase
    end

product = prod[63:0];

end


endmodule
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `*` in the RTL ?

Answer (score 0):

For `>>>` to perform signed shift the variable must be declared as signed.

```
reg signed [64:0] prod;
```

Short example [on eda playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Smm).

Also note that `prod = {32'b0,operand1};` is not a sign extension. You should probably be using:

```
prod = { {32{operand[31]}}, operand1 };
```

Comment: thank you, the signed declaration makes the code return the correct value, however the sign is still incorrect. And the algorithm require that I zero stuff the upper 32 bits of the variable `prod`, so for this implementation
`prod = {32'b0,operand1} ` is correct